# Car and Cdr in Scheme/Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

How exactly would you single out the 'x' variable in this scenario:

```
(define s '(5 4.x))
```

Using `(cdr s)` gives an output of `4.x`  But how would i go about singling out the `x` term so that the output would be only x while using only "car" and or "cdr"

`(cdr s)` gives me 4.x

`(cdr (cdr s))` gives me ()

`(cdr (car s))` gives me an error.  "cdr contract violation, expected pair? given: 1

Comment: `(cdr s)` gives `(4.x)`, a list with one symbol. Did you mean `(define s '(5 4 . x))`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `4.x` is not a pair. You need spaces around the `.` for it to create a pair.

```
(define s '(5 4 . x))
(cdr (cdr s))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(define s '(5 4.x))` defines s to be a list of 2 elements: `5` (a number) and `4.x` (a symbol).

Try `(define s '(5 4 . x))`